# Reflection Emit to create class instance

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, il

I want to use Reflection Emit to create an instance of a class with arbitrary constructor parameters. This is how my code looks like:

```
public delegate object ObjectActivator(params object[] args);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ao = new { ID = 10000, FName = "Sample", SName = "Name" };
    var t = ao.GetType();
    var info = t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(string) });
    var objActivatorEmit = GetActivatorEmit(info);
    var obj = createdActivatorEmit(4, "Foo", "Bar");
}
public static ObjectActivator GetActivatorEmit(ConstructorInfo ctor)
{
    ParameterInfo[] paramsInfo = ctor.GetParameters();
    DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("CreateInstance", typeof(object), new Type[] { typeof(object[]) });
    ILGenerator gen = method.GetILGenerator();
    for (int i = 0; i < paramsInfo.Length; i++)
    {
        Type t = paramsInfo[i].ParameterType;
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // Push array (method argument)
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i); // Push i
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref); // Pop array and i and push array[i]
        if( t.IsValueType )
        {
            gen.Emit( OpCodes.Unbox_Any, t ); // Cast to Type t
        }
        else
        {
            gen.Emit( OpCodes.Castclass, t ); //Cast to Type t
        }
    }
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    return (ObjectActivator)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(ObjectActivator));
}
```

The code fails with an `MethodAccessException` with the error message `Attempt by method 'DynamicClass.CreateInstance(System.Object[])' to access method '<>f__AnonymousType1'3<System.Int32,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>..ctor(Int32, System.__Canon, System.__Canon)' failed.`.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message indicates that the anonymous type's constructor isn't public.  I think anonymous type constructors are always `internal`, so you'll need to skip visibility checks by using a different `DynamicMethod` constructor:

```
DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("CreateInstance", typeof(object), new Type[] { typeof(object[]) }, true);
```

Note that this not work in partial trust scenarios.

Comment: I think it's a generic public ctor, based on: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/12/20/why-are-anonymous-types-generic.aspx

Comment: @Elisha - it's a public constructor on an internal type, so it's still inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use Reflection.Emit, and I would suggest you don't. Unless you know what you're doing or have some special need that can't be fulfilled by some other API, it's best to stay away.

There are 3 alternatives that are much easier to get right. Check it out:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public static class App
{
    public delegate object ObjectActivator(params object[] args);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ao = new { ID = 10000, FName = "Sample", SName = "Name" };
        var t = ao.GetType();
        var info = t.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(string) });
        if (info == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Info is null");
        }

        // This uses System.Linq.Expressions to create the delegate
        var activator = GetActivator(info);
        var newObj1 = activator(4, "Foo", "Bar");

        // This invokes the ConstructorInfo directly
        var newObj2 = info.Invoke(new object[] { 4, "Foo", "Bar" });

        // This uses System.Activator to dynamically create the instance
        var newObj3 = Activator.CreateInstance(t, 4, "Foo", "Bar");
    }

    // This uses System.Linq.Expressions to generate a delegate
    public static ObjectActivator GetActivator(ConstructorInfo ctor)
    {
        var args = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]), "args");
        var parameters = ctor.GetParameters().Select((parameter, index) => Expression.Convert(Expression.ArrayIndex(args, Expression.Constant(index)), parameter.ParameterType));
        return Expression.Lambda<ObjectActivator>(Expression.New(ctor, parameters), args).Compile();
    }
}
```

Note: Inspiration for the `GetActivator` method from [this post](http://rogeralsing.com/2008/02/28/linq-expressions-creating-objects/)

Comment: Thanks, but I was writing a microbenchmark to test all options and Emit was the only one that was not working.

Comment: I was struggling working with ILGenerator. using `Expression` was much easier. I used it to cache constructor call in to delegate. thank you so much